# Script has different output when called from python then when called from bash

Tags: python, linux, bash

I am making a tool so users can sink changelogs from new releases on perforce.
A user with certain rights has to login to download those logs. I need to get the p4 OAuth URL that returns when the p4 login command is ran.
This is what the code looks like in bash

```
p4 set P4PORT=ssl:XXXXXXXX
p4 set P4USER=XXXXXXXXX
p4 login > XXXXXXXX/temp/url.txt 2>&1 &
```

and that worked just fine. The url was printed out in the url.txt file.
I load this script as a template using python and write a new file with some changes, a number here a name there. I then call this script and then read the url from the file, but when I call it from my python code using

```
subprocess.run(['bash','XXXXXXXXXX/load_credentals.sh'])
```

A file url.txt is created, but it is empty.
I blocked out the file paths and ssh domain name for privacy reasons.

Comment: This is the kind of situation where using syscall-tracing tools to compare both invocations and figure out what's different in practice is appropriate. Until you figure out where they diverge, you don't know how to build a [mre] that lets us create the problem ourselves, because you don't know what variables are differing between the usage modes.

Comment: I personally strongly suggest [`sysdig`](https://github.com/draios/sysdig), but if installing kernel modules isn't going to fly in your environment, `strace -f` is better than nothing. Dig into what the three `p4` calls actually do and where they fail, and you'll be in a better place to ask a question about the specific failure mode.

Comment: BTW, one thing I _do_ recommend would be to log more aggressively. If you start your bash script with `exec >/tmp/p4-login-$$.log 2>&1; set -x` (after the shebang, of course), you'll have _something_ logged, even if that something just shows what the p4 commands that are being invoked are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When loading and making edits to the template I forgot to add new lines when building the new file.
I was doing

```
with open('filename') as file:
    file.write('blah')
```

instead of

```
with open('filename') as file:
    file.write('blah \n')
```